# I'm struggling to write numbers (0-10) into a CSV file. How do I change into a list, convert to integers, and have the number on each line?

Tags: python

## Writes numbers from 0 to 10 into a CSV file

import csv

```
fileW = open('numbers.csv', 'w')
fileW.write('0,')
fileW.write('\n1,')
fileW.write('\n2,')
fileW.write('\n3,')
fileW.write('\n4,')
fileW.write('\n5')
fileW.write('\n6,')
fileW.write('\n7,')
fileW.write('\n8,')
fileW.write('\n9,')
fileW.write('\n10')
fileW.close();
```

## Read the numbers into a list

```
fileR = open('numbers.csv')
contnts = fileR.read()
print(contents)
```

This is my code. How do I convert this into integers and change into a list so that when I print the contents I got one column of numbers: one number on each line like [0 on first line, 1 on second line, 2 on third line...]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pythonic way to save, obtain the numbers and create a list named int_list with all those integers:

```
with open('numbers.csv', 'w') as fileW:
    for i in range(11):
        fileW.write('%s\n'%i)

int_list = []
with open('numbers.csv','r') as fileR:
    for line in fileR:
        line = line.rstrip('\n') # read line and clean the EOL
        int_list.append(int(line))
        print(line) 

print(int_list)
```

Output:

> 0 
> 1
>  2
>  3
>  4
>  5
>  6
>  7
>  8
>  9
>  10
>  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Now you can operate the list.

Comment: Hi Jose! Your response really helped but when I get the output I'm getting the list but there are no brackets? Also I need to convert this into integers using this method I did above?

Comment: yes a list but when i print the list i need the list to be in a bracket like [0 in first line, 1 in second line, 2 in third line...]. The first one u gave me was good but how do u fix that to get a bracket? i also need to convert to int?

Comment: I need [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] to be looking like a column exactly. how do i do that?

Comment: @VRam, the output is a column, no? First, a column, and later, the print(int_list) output...

Comment: i just needed the column part but I checked with my prof and he said that format was fine. thank u for ur help!!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the Python "csv" module  https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html.  This makes it extremely easy to read and write CSV format.  For example,

```
import csv
import sys

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow([1, 2, 3])
```

With the csv module you can do many things easily, reading as well as writing, and this includes reading a whole CSV file pretty much in one gulp.

Answer (score 0):

let's use a for loop, shall we ?

```
# generate the list with commas
fileW = open('numbers.csv', 'w')
for i in xrange(11):
    fileW.write('%s,\n'%i)
fileW.close()


# open the file and read line by line    
with open('numbers.csv','r') as fileR:
    for line in fileR:
       # remove the trailing comma, and convert back to integer 
       print int(line[:-1]) +100
```

Comment: your print int(line[:-1]) +100  is giving me an error